# Sharepoint 2010 Service account for using the Object model

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, sharepoint-2010

I have created a facade web service for Sharepoint 2010 which performs some functions using the Object model (.NET 3.5 & WCF).

I'm just wondering what the minimum permissions I need to give the service account running the WCF service are? At the moment I have it running under the Sharepoint Farm account and it works fine but I would like to change it.

When I did change it I started getting a "FileNotFound" exception at the SPSite constructor.

I tried:

- Setting the new Service account as the owner of the site collection
- Giving that user dbowner rights to the Sharepoint config and content databases

However, the SPSite constructor was still throwing that exception until I changed it back to the Farm account.

Is there anything else I need to with with the service account user?

Thanks & happy new year!
John

Comment: The service account needs permissions on the content database where your site collections are stored. You could use the same account that is used as application pool account for the web application where the site collection is assigned to.